# More simple logic condition to check non-empty requirements

Tags: java, refactoring, logic, boolean

I have some simple logic to check if the field is valid:

```
private boolean isValidIfRequired(Object value) {
    return
        (required && !isEmpty(value)) || !required;
}
```

it tells that the field is valid if it's either required and not empty or not required.

I don't like this required || !required part. Something with just required would be better.
How do I simplify this method to make it more readable and simple?

Comment: What's the problem with `!required`? It's perfectly readable as it is. However, I'd probably flip the expression around to have the `!required` first, so it makes more grammatical sense when you read it out loud: "If not required, or if required and not empty".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How 'bout:

```
private boolean isValidIfRequired(Object value) {
    return !required || !isEmpty(value);
}
```

or (thanks, @Peter Lawrey)

```
private boolean isValidIfRequired(Object value) {
    return !(required && isEmpty(value));
}
```

In either case, if `required` is `false`, the `||` or `&&` expression will [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and `isEmpty` will never be called. If `required` is `true`, the second half of the `||` or `&&` will be evaluated, calling `isEmpty` and returning the (inverted) result of that call.

Comment: Yeah, just made  the same for myself.

Comment: And it has meaning: either value not required or not empty (in case if still required)

Comment: Peter: Yeah, that works nicely too (and @Vladimir, Peter's version will also short-circuit). Both are totally fine, it depends how you think about the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The expected return of isValidIfRequired() is to return true.

So the exceptional cases must be put at the beginning as guardian clausules:

```
private boolean isValidIfRequired(Object value) {

  if (required && empty(value))   //guardian clausule
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

for me the above code is more human-readable than using together expresions containing  ANDs ORs and negations

Comment: I think it's a good point to exclude special cases first. But in this particular case I would go for short code because it also reads well.